# Предупреждение об ошибке при дообучении GPT-2 с помощью библиотеки transformers в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Имеется скрипт для дообучения модели gpt2 с huggingface, но он постоянно выводит в консоль предупреждения такого типа: `Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1528700 > 1024). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors.` (Перевод: Длина последовательности индексов токенов больше указанной максимальной длины последовательности для данной модели (1528700 > 1024). Прогон этой последовательности через модель приведет к ошибкам индексации).

Как мне исправить это?

Вот сам скрипт обучения:

```
import torch, json, pyweb_progressbar
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2TokenizerFast, TextDataset, DataCollatorForLanguageModeling, Trainer, TrainingArguments
from datasets import load_dataset
from google.colab import drive
import torch

# Объявление переменных
txt_dataset_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/gtm/yandex_part_24.txt"
model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/gtm/gpt2_finetuned_0.11.3"
model_save_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/gtm/gpt2_finetuned_0.11.4"

num_epochs = 16
batch_size = 1024
per_device_train_batch_size = 2

# Загрузка токенизатора и модели
tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_path)

# Подготовка датасета для обучения
train_dataset = TextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path=txt_dataset_path,
    block_size=batch_size
)

# Создание объекта DataCollator
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False,
)

# Параметры обучения
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=model_save_path,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=num_epochs,
    per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
    save_steps=40_000,
    save_total_limit=100,
)

# Обучение модели
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=train_dataset
)

trainer.train()

# Сохранение модели и токенизатора
model.save_pretrained(model_save_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_save_path)
```

Comment: У вас там слишком длинные входные данные, что-то тут не то. Почитайте тут, но рецепты просто обрезать лишнее не уверен, что вам помогут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66954682/token-indices-sequence-length-is-longer-than-the-specified-maximum-sequence-leng